# Building a Angular Login System with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I have found so many tutorials of Angular Authentications systems using an External API etc. I want to only have the user login to my Database of users, like you would as in php.
How would i go about doing this?
All the Controllers/Services and Directives are currently in one file as i dont know how to separate them as of yet.

What framework would you suggest for a website that will allow users to post projects and such and other usergroups can get hired for those projects? I am looking for something with a nice feel like Angular. Suggestions?

This is what i have so far:

login.html:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">{{moduleTitle}}</h3>
    <form class="form-signin" name="loginForm" role="form">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="data.email">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="login()" data-ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            title: 'Login'
        }).
        when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
            controller: 'signupCtrl',
            title: 'SignUp'
        }).
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashCtrl',
            title: 'Dashboard'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404', templateUrl:'views/404.html' })
}]);

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, $route, $rootScope) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $rootScope.pageTitle = $route.current.title;
    $scope.moduleTitle = "Login to Firelance";

    $scope.login = function() {
        AuthService.loginUser(
            $scope.data.email, 
            $scope.data.password
        ).success(function(data) {
            alert('Success');
        }).error(function(data) {
            var alertPopup = alert(
                'Please check your credentials!'
            );
        });
    }
})

app.service('AuthService', function($q) {
    return {
        loginUser: function(name, pw) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = deferred.promise;

            if (name == 'savisaar2' && pw == 'naf44nss') {
                deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
            } else {
                deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
            }
            promise.success = function(fn) {
                promise.then(fn);
                return promise;
            }
            promise.error = function(fn) {
                promise.then(null, fn);
                return promise;
            }
            return promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using AngularJS as a front-end framework here, you would have to use some form of API and not directly access your database. I don't actually know of any JavaScript in-browser MySQL DBALs anyway, and on top of that, if there is/was one you'd have to store your database credentials in plain text and send them to everybody using your application as part of the application (not a good idea!). On top of that, your database would have to be open to external access (also not a good idea!).

Controllers manipulate the view. You assign methods and properties on the scope, and they are available in the view. You can then use those methods and properties in the view and manipulate them.

Directives are reusable blocks. You can put specific bits of logic in them, have them interact with services, and they work similarly to the view and controller described above.

Services are where the real business logic should go, you should call upon services in your controllers / directives to *do* things. Like, for example, you could have a service that is an API client, and another which uses that API client to handle a certain area of that API, or maybe have a service for processing data to show in a chart, or whatever. The idea is, services are also reusable, testable, and mockable. If you put your logic into a controller, it is not easily reusable.

Comment: So what would be the best method to adding Authentication to an Angular App. Or Perhaps Angular is not a good method for my project? I am building a website where users can post projects and hire people for them, and i though having a nice quick system using angular would be nice, what do you think? Is there a better framework for this kind of project? Thanks

Comment: Angular is a great framework, it simply means you'll probably need to build some kind of API to work alongside it as the back-end. There are plenty of frameworks in plenty of languages to do this already, and you can see really nice results with it :)

Comment: since this is a client side framework, is there issues with authentication or security I general? I love the speed on the framework and how it works in general however I am trying to understand how to structure the code alongside mvc pattern which I have never used. You said I would need to build an API I think that should be fine in php right? I mean as long as the return is JSON. Also what do you mean in regards to not accessing the DB directly?

Comment: You could build the API in PHP, sure :). I think your main security concerns would not lie with Angular, but rather with the API you build. By not accessing the DB directly, I mean, from the client-side. Your API would be fine to access it directly, because it would be quite likely that your API would be running on the same server, or within the same network as your database server thus eliminating that concern.